# I write a arrow function but when compile it said function is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I dont know why it is not defined ，i think i defined，
when compiling 'renderMenu' is not defined  no-undef，
the code like that，
export default class NavLeft extends Component{

```
componentWillMount(){
    const menuTreeNode = this.renderMenu(MenuList)
    this.setState=({
        menuTreeNode
    })
}

renderMenu = (data)=>{
    return data.map((item)=>{
        if(item.children){
            return(
            <SubMenu title={item.title} key={item.key}>
                {this.renderMenu(item.children)}
            </SubMenu>)

        }
        return <Menu.Item title={item.title} key={item.key} >
        {item.title}
    </Menu.Item>

    })
}

render(){
    return (
    <div>
        <div className = 'logo'>
            <img src='/assets/logo-ant.svg' alt = ''/>
            <h1>imooc ms</h1>
        </div>
        <Menu theme='dark'>
          {this.state.menuTreeNode}
        </Menu>
    </div>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The below changes would fix the issue
Change

```
  componentWillMount()
```

To

```
  componentDidMount()
```

And change

```
 renderMenu = function(data){
```

To

```
 renderMenu = data =>{
```

Comment: Did you change componentWillMount to componentDidMount?

Comment: i changed but still error,somebody said about eslint ,but i don't how to Modify configuration